# Page rotation with pstricks and font package

Tags: pstricks, pst-eucl, sourcesanspro

I have a problem with a simple example (text rotating). Here's the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,3.2)(15,8.2)
        \uput[u]{45}(.5,4){centaines}   
    \end{pspicture} \psset{unit=1cm}
\end{document}
```

This compilation gives the result in the left, but if I change the 45 with 90 (or any number above 45), the compilation gives the result at the right with a page rotated.

If I discard the line `sourcesanspro` (`\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}`) package, the word "centaines" is rotated correctly without changing page orientation.

[image: Left image : correct page rotation / Right image : bad page rotation !!]

Can somebody help? Thanks a lot ! :)

**Note:** Compilation made under Windows 11, `MiKTeX` 21.10 32-bit and TexMaker 5.1.2. Packages updated just before compilation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Compiling with `xelatex`  (under Windows 7) I have no such problem.

Comment: Run the document with `lualatex` and it should be fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ghostscript tries to guess the orientation of the page and is fooled by the vertical text. You need to pass the option `-dAutoRotatePages=/None` to ps2pdf to avoid this. You can also pass it as special in your document:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}

\usepackage[default]{sourcesanspro}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\special
  { ps::
     /setdistillerparams  where
     { pop << /AutoRotatePages  /None >> setdistillerparams }
            if
  }


\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(0,3.2)(15,8.2)
        \uput[u]{90}(.5,4){centaines}
    \end{pspicture} \psset{unit=1cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Adding "-dAutoRotatePages=/None" didn't work but the other solution did. :)

Comment: you perhaps need `-dAutoRotatePages#/None` instead, that depends a bit on how you actually call ps2pdf (but imho the document version is nicer anyway).